# Updating array data in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures, insert-update

So here is my problem. I know there is a fair bit of literature on this site about this type of issue but I am confused about how several of these issues intertwine for my problem. First I have an array of row data that needs to be updated or inserted based on a remote id value within that array, in this case `value_c`. This array corresponds to a row instance from table foo. Basically, if a record with a matching `value_c` exists in the database then update that record otherwise insert the new record payload. The data structure of the array corresponds to the row schema of table foo in our db. This is the schema (obfuscated for safety):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foos` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `value_a` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
     `value_b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `value_c` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     .
     .
     .
     .
     `value_x` enum('enum_a','enum_b','enum_c','enum_d') DEFAULT NULL,
     `value_y` text,
     `value_z` enum('daily','monthly','weekly') DEFAULT NULL,
     `value_aa` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
     `value_bb` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=829762 ;
```

There is a lot of data, and the plan in as followed. String-ify this data send it to a stored procedure that would then update or insert as needed. Something like the following (note that this will be happening in a model within codeigniter):

```
public function update_or_insert($event_array_payload)
{
    // string-ify the data
    $mod_payload = implode('<delimiter>', $event_array_payload)

    //deal with NULLs in array
    $mod_payload = $this->deal_with_nulls($mod_payload);

    $this->stored_procedure_lib->update_or_insert_payload($mod_payload);
}

// then elsewhere in the stored procedure library
public function update_or_insert_payload($foo)
{
    $this->_CI->db->query('CALL update_or_insert_foo(\'$foo\')');
}
```

My issue is as followed. A single string value is passed into the stored procedure. Then it needs to be parsed apart and places into either a single update or a single insert statement. I could create a variable for each column of the `foo` table and a loop to populate each variable and update/insert that way, but the foo table is very likely to be extended, and I do not want to create bugs further down the line. Is there a way to dynamically place the parsed apart contents of a string representation of an array into a single update or insert statement. I'm not sure if that is even possible, but I feel like a work around I do not know about might exist. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do You mean that You would like to have a procedure update_or_insert(listOfValuesAsString) instead of using INSERT/UPDATE because in the future You may have more columns?

Comment: @Gustek Well its more that I want to be able to inert or update in the same operation block. This is because it will save additional calls to the database server, which will (in the long term) save a lot of processing power and money.

Comment: So maybe You simply need [insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or if not provide a pseudo code of procedure You trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a definitive answer but it would be an option to try.

If you want to avoid sending many parameters the procedure, you can create a table called `foos_tmp` with the same structure `foos` but with one field aditional `id_foos_tmp` (pk and autoincrement) and enter the array in table `foos_tmp`. Then the procedure you send only the `id_foos_tmp` of the table `foos_tmp` generated and internally the procedure to do a SELECT `foos_tmp` table and get the data that you had before in the array.

I hope it helps somewhat.

Greetings.